# Connect OpenVPN clients to clients only (without server access)

Tags: windows, openvpn

I have setup an OpenVPN server (on Windows), that allows clients to talk to each other and the server, using `client-to-client` in the servers conf file.

Now I want to restrict the clients access to each other only, so they cannot access any server resources (shares etc.).
Is there a configuration option, that blocks traffic to the server itself and just allows the clients to reach each other?

Of course I could configure the server's firewall, but maybe there is something easier already lingering in OpenVPN's configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did not find any option in OpenVPN itself to block reaching the server itself, so I blocked access to the server using the firewall after all.